# What does the "_" type mean in swift error messages?

Tags: swift, generics, type-inference

Occasionally when using generics, I get an error message that refers to a "_" as a parameter. It doesn't appear to be documented. What does it mean?

As an example, I get the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'JawDroppingFeat<Superhero>' to closure result type 'JawDroppingFeat<_>'
```

when I try to compile:

```
protocol SuperheroType {
  typealias Superpower
}

struct JawDroppingFeat<Superhero: SuperheroType where Superhero: Arbitrary, Superhero.Superpower: Arbitrary>: Arbitrary {
  let subject: Superhero
  let superpowerUsed: Superhero.Superpower

  static var arbitrary: Gen<JawDroppingFeat<Superhero>> {
    get {
      return Gen.zip(Superhero.arbitrary, Superhero.Superpower.arbitrary)
        .map{ (x: Superhero, y: Superhero.Superpower) in
          JawDroppingFeat(subject: x, superpowerUsed: y)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The Gen and Arbitrary types are from SwiftCheck and the relevant declarations are:

```
public struct Gen<A> {
  public static func zip<A, B>(gen1: SwiftCheck.Gen<A>, _ gen2: SwiftCheck.Gen<B>) -> SwiftCheck.Gen<(A, B)>
  public func map<B>(f: A -> B) -> SwiftCheck.Gen<B>
}

public protocol Arbitrary {
  public static var arbitrary: SwiftCheck.Gen<Self> { get }
}
```

I assume that the `<_>` is something to do with swift failing to infer the type parameter rather than an image of Chris Lattner wincing at me. But does it have a more precise (and documented) meaning?

### Edit

My best current theory is that when Swift fails to infer a type parameter, instead of failing immediately, it assigns a null (`_`) type, which results in the actual compile error downstream at some point where an incompatible type (in my case, the parameters to `.map`) is passed.

Comment: If you've solved this, it would be cool if you posted your solution code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It means you have incomplete type information in a return value of parameter.

In this case the .map function is returning a generic JawDroppingFeat for which you did not specify the embedded type.

I assume you meant to write

```
 JawDroppingFeat<SuperHero>(subject: x, superpowerUsed: y)
```

Comment: Almost. The JawDroppingFeat type was inferred fine without an explicit annotation. The problem was that I didn't annotate the `Gen` type when I called its static `.zip` function. Since the arguments use the function's type parameters rather than the struct's, it was unable to give infer a concrete type from the Gen struct. Which manifested as requiring `_` as the parameters for the `.map` call...

Answer (score 1):

In general, my experience is that this error message appears to be constructed backwards. "Cannot convert value of type X to Y" seems to mean "You supplied Y, but what's needed is X."